# Send Push notification to IOS Device using APNS and DataService using PHP

Tags: php, ios

I m Trying to send a push notification to IOS Device.

My code like that for send a notification to ios device.

```
if($db_to[0]['platform']=='1') {
    $messagesArray[]=array(
      'DeviceToken'=>$db_to[0]['device_id'],
      'Message'=>$msg,
      'Sound'=>'default',
      'noti_status'=>$db_to[0]['noti_status'],                
      'Type'=>'1',
      'pid'=>$Promotion[0]['pid'],
      'rest_id'=>$Promotion[0]['rest_id'] ,
      'pnm'=>$Promotion[0]['pname'] ,
      'pimg'=>$Promotion[0]['pimage'] , 
      'pdesc'=>$Promotion[0]['pdesc'] , 
      'p_bk_img'=>$Promotion[0]['p_background_img'] , 
      'p_d_img'=>$Promotion[0]['p_detail_img'] , 
    );
}
```

In PHP side I got these type of array when I printed the $messagesArray array.

But in IOS side he/she was got the different response like that.

```
aps = {
        alert = "sent you a Notification";
        sound = default;
        type = 1;
      };
```

So my Question is that , is there any changes in to the apns file or dataservice api files ???

IOS got only Type and Sound , and Notification Message which one I Send.
they didn't get the whole response which I was print it my side.

so Guys Please help me.
How can I Solve these.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're not telling us what library and/or platform you are using. Obviously there's something between your initial object and APNS that uses some of the parameters you set to build the notification.

Comment: @jcaron : i m using these code in web-services. and Apns.php and DataService.php for sending a push-notification to ios.

Comment: Please provide a link to the libraries you're using if they're public, or the relevant parts of the doc if not. We can't help you with your issue if you don't provide any of the useful details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, which parameters you want in response just pass all parameters in function..